# Persistent data structures in RAM computational model

Tags: ds.data-structures

Always when I read about any efficient persistent data structures they use pointer computational model. I'm wondering if you know any efficient implementation which uses power of RAM model?

Answer (score 3):

- [Paul F. Dietz's "Fully Persistent Arrays"](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/fileDownloadForInstitutionalItem.action?itemId=5260&itemFileId=8146) uses a variant on van Emde Boas trees, which rely on arrays and also on integers being represented as words.
- [Brodal et al.'s "Fully Persistent B-Trees"](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/pub/soda12.html) relies on arrays.
- [Davoodi et al.'s "Cache-Oblivious Persistence"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5492) applies a persistence transform to data structures that don't necessarily work in the pointer model.
- [The Bentley-Saxe logarithmic method, also known as cache-oblivious lookahead arrays](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/i-dreamt-of-a-data-structure-does-it-exist) is naturally partially persistent, and relies on arrays for the insert time to be $o(\log_B n)$ in an external-memory setting.