# Partition points in the plane

Tags: ds.algorithms, computational-geometry

Given $n=2k$ points in the plane and also given positive real value $r$. Is there an algorithm that partition points into two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that each group contains exactly $k$ points and also distance between each pair of points in $G_1$ has distance at most $r$?

I seek for an algorithm that solve above problem on $o(n^2)$ or  a proof that show us we can't solve above problem in less than $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: Possibly related: comments following https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51118/a-problem-in-understanding-an-algorithm (including link to now-deleted https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51279/partition-points-into-two-equal-clusters)

Comment: @NealYoung Thank you in advance. Could you give me some hint about this problem?